# showing logcat on android devices

Tags: android, logcat

is there a way to show logcat (such as in eclipse) overlay in our Android devices? if possible, can anyone give me a hint on how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Note that this will no longer work as of Android 4.1. An app can only see messages logged by its process, not messages logged by other processes.

Answer (score 0):

try this app [aLogCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5qdGIuYWxvZ2NhdCJd) the best one!

Answer (score 0):

try the app alogrec from google market u can record all your logs and save on the sdcard